# How to change GNOME's window management behavior?

Tags: x11, gnome, window-management

I am using GNOME on Xorg with Fedora 25. When I activate a Window, for example by pressing a shortcut key I defined in the application or by for example double clicking a document file to open LibreOffice, GNOME's notification area at the top center of the screen reads "X is ready", where X is the application in question. I really hate this behavior and would rather see it open the application and make it visible on the screen, especially when I activate, for example GoldenDict, using its keyboard shortcuts to show the Window. 
So, the questions is how such GNOME behavior can be configured?

Comment: Which window manager are you using, and are you willing to change?

Comment: @Gilles I small gear beside login password field when clicked shows Gnome on Xorg selected. There are others in the list like Plasma,  Gnome on Wayland,  XFCE,  etc.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this gnome-addon maybe can work for you
[Steal my focus](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/234/steal-my-focus/)